# How to generate stats or reports for multi-sites?

Tags: multi-sites, log-messages

We've a large deployment of multi-sites, each site with its own database, and I am looking at generating reports from these sites and making those available online in some format.

For e.g., our sites implement many redirects. I want to be able to pull a report on what redirects are in use by which site. I can readily do this via drush and shell scripts, but it would be nice to have a "stats site" to do the generating of these kinds of reports for all sites in a multi-site setup.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do this:

I created a "meta" site and database in the system where I added a new table called "databases".  In that table I store the access info of all the DBs in the system.

Then loading an array from a query to that table, query the other DBs individually using the methods outlined here:
http://drupal.org/node/18429

Answer (score 1):

The [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363) module seems to me like a pretty perfect fit to address this requirement. No PHP coding involved, just add your custom SQL queries to fit your requirements for getting the data you need, and then use your XHTML / CSS skills to beef up your output (report). Eventually adding some charts to it also, which even support drill-down links.

Here is the intro near the top of that linked page (use the link for more details, and its child pages):

> Forena Reports is built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a
>   database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports.
>
> It is designed to leverage existing knowledge of HTML, CSS, SQL and
>   JavaScript to help you create rich interactive web reports.

Its [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) you'd want to take advantage of in this case would be either "Drupal" or "PDO" ... done! Don't believe me (yet), just try it in your own environment).

Be aware: I'm a co-maintainer of forena, and created most of the community docu for it.